# Index of a vector field on the unit sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-fields

Let $F$ be a vector field defined on $\mathbb{S}^2$ such that
$$F(x,y, z)-[ F(x,y, z)\cdot k ]k=F(-x,-y, z)-[F(-x,-y, z)\cdot k]k$$ and $F(x,y,z)=F(-x,-y,-z)$. Here $k=(0,0,1)$.

Indeed $F=(f_1,f_2, f_3)$ such that $f_1, f_2$ are symmetric about $xy-$plane and $f_3$ is anti symmetric about $xy-$ plane.

Suppose $F$ is continuous everywhere except $(0,0, \pm1)$. What can we say about the index of $F$ near $(0,0, \pm1)$? Can we conclude that they are even numbers? Or can they be both equal to 1?

I am just learning about index of maps, and I understand that this might be a trivial question.

Comment: Good question, but now you can see why we want to see some effort in your part. We have no idea what your working definition of index is.

Comment: I use the definition of index here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Hopf_theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that by vector field you mean a vector field everywhere tangent to the sphere. The tangent space at the poles is horizontal, so you should just think about a vector field $g$ on the plane with $g(x,y)=g(-x,-y)$. I don’t know your definition of index. For example, any regular value of $g/|g|$ mapping circle to circle will have an even number of preimages. Or, consider the vector field on a small circle centered at the origin; it starts and ends at the same place at any pair of opposite points, and so it makes twice that number of turns as we go entirely around the circle.

Comment: Thank you Ted. I want to use the Poincare-Hopf theorem to show that such map does not exists. If the index of both points are even, then $F$ must have other zeros right?

Comment: Not at all. The Euler characteristic of the sphere is $2$, isn't it? Indeed, you should be able to write down a very standard vector field on the sphere with this property and with zeroes only at the north and south pole. (Oh, and my first justification is using the definition you linked from Wikipedia.)

Comment: If the index of both vanishing points of $F$ is even, then doesn't it follow from Poincaré–Hopf theorem that the sum of the index of these two points must be two?  That implies that index of each of the poles must be 1, an odd number. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, I was stooopid. Yes, the obvious vector field I'm thinking of does *not* have the right symmetry property and does have index $1$ at each pole. So your are absolutely correct to conclude that a vector field on the sphere with these symmetries cannot exist. The obvious vector field with the even symmetry at one pole comes from the function $f(z)=z^2$ on $\Bbb C$ and it will be nonzero at infinity.

Comment: Thank you so much. Ted.

Comment: You're most welcome. Good question. When you're satisfied that you understand it, please accept the answer so that the question does not stay on the unanswered list. :)